# How can I simply graph JSON data?

Tags: json, api, curl, graph, jq

I'm working on an application that exposes an API. In this Rest API, I can retrieve statistics about the application.

I'd like a simple way to graph json data results by using a curl command and use of jq.

Is there a library that would help to natively display this data in a graph ?

Answer (score 0):

There must be a gazillion alternatives, depending on what you mean by "natively", but it might be worth mentioning that Altair is a python package that allows one to specify the data source

- "as a url string pointing to a json or csv formatted text file"

See https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html

Comment: Thank you peak, that's exactly what I need !